# Android. Список в стиле Material Design

Tags: android, recyclerview, material-design

Подскажите, как реализовать средствами android (без сторонних библиотек) список с сайта о material design. Точнее, как реализовать алфавитный указатель, что бы буква отображалась один раз перед каждой новой буквой имени (список отсортирован).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мб покопаться в исходниках сторонних библиотек , как вариант)

Comment: @Романыч Хм... как вариант, но я таких пока не нашел. Я пытался ковыряться в паре библиотек, мне пока сложно разбираться в чужом коде, но это хорошая практика. Если есть библиотеки, подскажите.

Comment: http://www.androhub.com/sectioned-recyclerview-android/ вот , и вот нечто похожее: https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/4c189fb1124df4556058    Sectioned RecyclerView. В нете полно примеров, посмотрите.